# jQuery, bPopup - how to position popup in bottom right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, bpopup

I want to create a popup with bPopup jQuery plugin, and position it in the bottom right part of the screen. bPopup has an option called 'position', but it only uses top and left coordinates.

I could set the position in CSS and use !important, which works, but then I lose the slide in animation.

Answer (score 1):

i have not use the bPopup plugin in jquery but i assume you can achieve it like this
80% from the left position and 80% from the top position or just change it whatever suits you

```
$('element').bPopup({
        follow: [false, false], //x, y
        position: ["90%","90%"] //x, y
    });
```

Comment: Hi noobHere, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the popup stops working if I use percentage, as you suggested. Also, I need an exact solution that will position my popup exactly 0 pixels from the right and bottom edges.

Comment: i have tried and it works .. have you not forgotten the double quotation in the position array value? like the example i gave you?

Comment: I can double-check tomorrow. But still, this solution would require me to set my popup's dimensions to 20%x20%, which I'm not quite able to. My popup has fixed dimensions.

Comment: Sorry noobHere, this still doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Томица Кораћ - i updated it would you mind to check your code . .

Answer (score 0):

You can position your bPopup element with regular CSS (as you mentioned) and then create the animation manually:

```
#element_to_pop_up { 
   position:absolute;
   right:10px;
   bottom:5px;
}

$("#element_to_pop_up").animate({width:'toggle'},350); //or any other animation
```